# File access speed vs database access speed

Tags: php, database, file-io

The site I am developing in php makes many MySQL database requests per page viewed. Albeit many are small requests with properly designed index's. I do not know if it will be worth while to develop a cache script for these pages.

1. Are file I/O generally faster than database requests? Does this depend on the server? Is there a way to test how many of each your server can handle?
2. One of the pages checks the database for a filename, then checks the server to see if it exists, then decides what to display. This I would assume would benefit from a cached page view?

Also if there is any other information on this topic that you could forward me to that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're doing read-heavy access (looking up filenames, etc) you might benefit from [memcached](https://www.php.net/memcached). You could store the "hottest" (most recently created, recently used, depending on your app) data in memory, then only query the DB (and possibly files) when the cache misses. Memory access is far, far faster than database or files.

If you need write-heavy access, a database is the way to go. If you're using MySQL, use InnoDB tables, or another engine that supports row-level locking. That will avoid people blocking while someone else writes (or worse, writing anyway).

But ultimately, it depends on the data.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on how the data is structured, how much there is and how often it changes.

If you've got relatively small amounts, of relatively static data with relatively simple relationships - then flat files are the right tool for the job.

Relational databases come into their own when the connections between the data are more complex.  For basic 'look up tables' they can be a bit overkill.

But, if the data is constantly changing, then it can be easier to just use a database rather than handle the configuration management by hand - and for large amounts of data, with flat files you've got the additional problem of how do you find the one bit that you need, efficiently.

Comment: Another thing databases offer that flat files don't is concurrency control.  In a write-heavy context, many processes writing to a single flat file can be problematic.

A nice compromise between custom, flat files, and a full RDBMS is SQLite -- there are more than a few SQLite backed sites out there.

Answer (score 4):

This really depends on many factors. If you have a fast database with much data cached in the RAM or a fast RAID system, chances are bad, that you will gain much from simple file system caching on the web server. Also think about scalibility. Under high workload a simple caching mechanism might easily become a bottle neck while a database is well designed to handle high work loads.
If there are not so much requests and you (or the operating system) is able to keep the cache in RAM, you might be able to gain some performance. But now the question arises, if it is realy neccessary to perform caching under low work load.

Answer (score 3):

From plain performance perspective, it is wiser to tune the database server and not complicate the data access logic with intermediate file caches. A good database server would do the caching on its own if the results are cacheable. (I'm not sure what is teh case with mysql).

If you have performance problems, you should profile the pages to see the real bottlenecks. Even when you are -like me- a fan of the optimized codes, putting a stronger/more hardware into the equation is cheaper on the long run.

If you still need to use caches, consider using an existing solution, like memcached.